# Finding the PID values for a vehicle control system

Tags: pid, autonomous-car

I'm trying to design a PID system for the longitudinal control of an autonomous vehicle. I figured out about most of it but I'm trying to figure out the Kp, Ki and Kd values. This is an illustration of what I'm working with:
[image]

So the PID controller outputs u, which is the acceleration value. However, I don't know how to find the Kp, Ki and Kd.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/20580/13242, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/66965/5874.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the manual Ziegler-Nichols method on manual tuning, I wanted to point out that the dynamics of the throttle/brake might not be symmetric. In that case, the set of Kp, Ki, Kd working for throttle (acceleration), might not work for braking (deceleration).

Comment: So if I had to write this in Python, what would be my inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Kp, Kd, Ki are called gains of the controller and can be found using manual tuning or via some techniques for example the Ziegler-Nichols method which is more precise.
And you can use different software for example MATLAB to achive the desired controller response and can calculate PID gains.
For more information on PID gains tuning, I would like to refer a previous answer, which will elaborate in detail:

[What are good strategies for tuning PID loops?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-are-good-strategies-for-tuning-pid-loops)