# PID controller for slowly varying system

Tags: pid, imu

I am making a robot that is required to move in a straight line, but it is slowly turning on the left or right, this error keeps accumulating (eventually resulting in a very large radius turn). So, now I have decided to use an IMU sensor to get the yaw value and use it in the PID controller. So I just want to know which combination of P, I, and D would be best for this application.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Exchange! Tuning a PID loop isn't always easy, but there is another Stack Exchange post that might help outline the general process:
https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-are-good-strategies-for-tuning-pid-loops

Comment: Thanks Man!!!, that will definitely help a lot.